# Trying to get the username of the user that runs the ping command and log it

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
const TOKEN = "mybotstoken";
const CLIENT_ID = "mybotsclientid";

const { REST, Routes } = require('discord.js');

const commands = [
  {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'Replies with Pong!',
  },
];

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(TOKEN);

(async () => {
  try {
    console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

    await rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands(CLIENT_ID), { body: commands });

    console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
})();

const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
  if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

  if (interaction.commandName === 'ping') {
    const user = interaction.author;

    const username = user.username;
    console.log(`Got a ping execute request from: ${username}`);

    await interaction.reply('Pong!');
    console.log(`Execute succesful`);
  }
});

client.login(TOKEN);
```

What's wrong with this code?

I'm getting the error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because there is no `interaction.author`. You probably thought that it's like `message.author`. There is an [`interaction.user`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Interaction?scrollTo=user) or an `interaction.member`, so you can use the former if you want to get the author's username:

```js
const username = interaction.user.username;
```